# Issues when using HuggingFace `accelerate` with `fp16`

Tags: pytorch, huggingface, distributed-training

I'm trying to use `accelerate` module to parallelize my model training. But I have troubles to use it when training models with `fp16`. If I load the model with `torch_dtype=torch.float16`, I got `ValueError: Attempting to unscale FP16 gradients.`. But if I don't load the model with half precision I will get a CUDA out of memory error. Below are the details of this problem:

I'm fine tuning a 2.7B CLM on one A100 - 40GB GPU (I will be working on a much larger model, but I want to use this model to test my training process to make sure everything works as expected). I initially started with a training script without `accelerate` and without `Trainer`. I can successfully train the model when I load the model in half precision with:

```py
# here device = 'cuda'
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name, torch_dtype=torch.float16).to(device)
```

I have to load the model in half precision otherwise I will get a CUDA out of memory error. I simplified my script and uploaded [here](https://gist.github.com/weiqi-dyania/a16cb88ea3dc0433c6b698c6bb26911d) as a demonstration. When loading the model with half precision, it takes about 27GB GPU memory out of 40GB in the training process. It has plenty of rooms left on the GPU memory.

Now I want to utilize the `accelerate` module (potentially with `deepspeed` for larger models in the future) in my training script. I made the following changes:

```
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name, torch_dtype=torch.float16)
accelerator = Accelerator(cpu=False, mixed_precision='fp16')
...
model, optimizer, train_dataloader, eval_dataloader = accelerator.prepare(
    model, optimizer, train_dataloader, eval_dataloader
)
...
# in training loop, I updated `lose.backward()` to:
accelerator.backward(loss)
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/weiqi-dyania/054de78141a76239ff568542f3883a51#file-run_clm_no_trainer_accelerator-py) is the updated script. I also configured `accelerate` with `accelerate config`. The `default_config.yaml` can be found from the same Gist.

Now when I tried to launch the script on the same machine with `accelerate launch --fp16 <script_path>`. I got an error `ValueError: Attempting to unscale FP16 gradients.`. So I removed `torch_dtype=torch.float16` from model loading and rely on `accelerate` to downcast the model weight to half precision. But now I got CUDA out of memory error.

To summarize:

1. I can train the model successfully when loading it with `torch_dtype=torch.float16` and not using `accelerate`.
2. With `accelerate`, I cannot load the model with `torch_dtype=torch.float16`. It gives `ValueError: Attempting to unscale FP16 gradients.`.
3. If I don't load the model with `torch_dtype=torch.float16` and use `fp16` with `accelerate`, I got CUDA out of memory error.

So my question is: how can I train the model on a single A100 - 40GB GPU with `accelerate`?

I included one script [without `accelerate`](https://gist.github.com/weiqi-dyania/a16cb88ea3dc0433c6b698c6bb26911d) and one [with `accelerate`](https://gist.github.com/weiqi-dyania/054de78141a76239ff568542f3883a51#file-run_clm_no_trainer_accelerator-py). I would like them to have the same behavior in terms of GPU memory consumption.

Comment: If I see correctly then [accelerator.prepare](https://github.com/huggingface/accelerate/blob/ecd128888c30355a6546c287f5776d19859f4ff4/src/accelerate/accelerator.py#L1234) will only autocast the model's forward function to fp16 but not the model weights itself? This might explain why you are not able to load the model using accelerate mixed precision.

Comment: did you solve? I have exact same issue